# Bash code word occurance counting within a directory of texts

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cpu-word

I'm trying to find out how to get count of how many of these files each word occurs in. For example, I have a directory with 10 recipe texts and i want to be able to find out, for example, how many of the texts the word 'pepper' occurs with a result like, '8 pepper'.

I know how to to word counts and the like but this is a bit over my head I think, I would really appreciate some help.

For an example of the vein of what i'm talking about, this is a word count command i figured out

```
cat test.txt | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr -d '[:punct:]' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find -type f  \
  | xargs tr  -c '[:alpha:]' '\n' \
  | tr '[:upper]' '[:lower:]' \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | grep pepper
```

This

1. finds all files in subdirectory;
2. concatenates them, replacing all that is not a letter with newline (this will produce
   lines with single words, and a lot of empty lines);
3. converts to lowercase (use of POSIX classes will preserve non-US characters);
4. sorts, and collapses the same <strike>word</strike> lines to produce something like
   a word occurrence graph

   ```
   42 
   16 add
   9 the
   8 jalapeño
   8 pepper
   7 lot
   ```
5. and filters that result to show only the line `8 pepper`.

You might want to replace or improve the *tr* command depending on what you expect in the files, or qualify the *find* to match only files with certain name template, etc.

Comment: I would change the `tr` to something like `tr -c a-zA-Z '\n'` to take care of punctuation so *e.g.* `away,"` doesn't show up as a separate word from `away`.  You'll have a lot of blank lines that way, but you can get rid of them with a `grep .` or just let the `sort | uniq` collapse them down to one line with a big count.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following

```
 find <directory path>  -name "*pepper*" -type f  |wc -l
```

Will list all files that has pepper and count them

Other Alternative (if you are in the directory where you recipies are)

```
ls -l|grep -E '*pepper*'|wc -l
```

Comment: Ahh right that makes sense but unfortunately sed commands don't work for me as I am in terminal on mac. Would there be a way to do this with cat instead do you know? Also how would the command line change to look for the occurrence count of all words that appear in multiple files as apposed to just specifically pepper? I was just using that as an example

Comment: To find all words with pepper and get a count try "grep -o -E 'pepper' 'my_file' |wc -l"

Comment: Let me rephrase, How do I count occurrences of a word in all the files of a directory? But with count incremented only once per word per file. Also I don't just want one specific word, i want a list of all the multiple word occurrences. If it was just one word I could just use 'grep -l word *|wc -l' but how would I get it to list all the words that occur multiple times in different files?

Comment: okay I edited my answer and included a small script you can use..hope this is helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

How about `grep -l`? For instance, `grep -l pepper *` will list all the files that contain "pepper".  `grep -l pepper * | wc -l` will just tell you how many such files there are..

Comment: Or `grep -l pepper -r` if you want to recurse to subdirs, and you can further refine that with `--include` or `--exclude`.